# NGRX - Multiple actions on single effect

Tags: action, effects, ngrx

So this is my effect..

```
@Effect() uploadImages$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ProjectActions.UPLOAD_IMAGES)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .flatMap(project => this.service.uploadImages(project))
    .switchMap((project) => Observable.of(
      this.imageActions.loadImages(),
      this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess(project),
    ));
```

Trying to load a list of images from an API before the uploadImagesSuccess fires.

I've attempted to use .concatMap and .mergeMap instead of .switchMap but that doesn't seem to be what it is.

Pretty new to Effects and Observables, and from what I've come across nothing has lead me to any answers.

Just need to fire one after the other has completed.

**Edit 1**

So loadImages() fires and once it completes an API call it fires loadImagesSuccess(). I suppose what I'm going for is along the lines of..

```
@Effect() uploadImages$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ProjectActions.UPLOAD_IMAGES)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .flatMap(project => this.service.uploadImages(project))
    .switchMap((project) => Observable.of(
      this.imageActions.loadImages(),
      this.imageActions.loadImagesSuccess(), 
      this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess(project),
  ));
```

And in a more general sense, I'm saving a photo to a project on an API. I want to refresh my ImageState before the uploadImagesSuccess() payload reaches my selector and has an undefined image path due to the ImageState not being updated in time.

**Edit 2**

I came by this solution to use ForkJoin, https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/64

```
@Effect() uploadImages$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ProjectActions.UPLOAD_IMAGES)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .flatMap(project => {
    let projectInfo$ = this.projectService.uploadImages(project);
    let imageInfo$ = this.imageService.loadImages();

    return Observable.forkJoin(projectInfo$, imageInfo$);
  })
  .mergeMap((results: any[]) => {
    let myActions: any[] = [];
    let actionGenerators = [
      (data: any) => {
        return this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess(data);
      },
      (data: any) => {
        return this.imageActions.loadImagesSuccess(data);
      }
    ];

    results.forEach((data: any, index: number) => {
      myActions.push(actionGenerators[index](data));
    });

    return Observable.from(myActions);
  });
```

Not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but it works as long as I delay the API call to load images. Without the delay, the images are being loaded prior to the new images being saved. Currently I'm delaying loadImages() on the API side.

If possible, I would like a better way to handle sending the API call to imageService.loadImages() until projectService.uploadImages() returns. Then once all the data is returned, fire the actions to update the store.

It was suggested to use concat instead of forkJoin in order to wait for one API call to finish before moving on to the next. But this then breaks results.Foreach() because results are no longer in an array.

Comment: You should return actions, do the functions inside the switchMap return actions?

Comment: @Meir maybe I'm wrong but I think they both do..

the loadImages runs an action and after the API call returns a loadImagesSuccess() action, which is similar to uploadImagesSuccess().

I wasn't having trouble returning data, but in the order of which the data returns.

Because the API takes longer, uploadImagesSuccess() fires before loadImagesSuccess() is called.

Ideally I would like the loadImagesSuccess to call after the uploadImagesSuccess is called, but I can't figure that out.

Comment: What does this.imageActions.loadImages() do?  Is there a side effect listening to loadImages where it is hitting an api to get a set of images?

Comment: @seescode yes, there is a side effect listening loadImages() and once returned from the API fires loadImagesSuccess().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this.  Instead of using the load images action just do the load images api call within your upload images side effect.  Something like this:

```
@Effect() uploadImages$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ProjectActions.UPLOAD_IMAGES)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .mergeMap(project => this.service.uploadImages(project)
     .mergeMap(() => {
        return this.otherService.loadImages()
          .map((images) => this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess({ project: project, images: images))
      }
  ));
```

Then you can have both reducers update state by listening to the UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS action:

```
export default function ProjectReducer (state = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
            return // do your update with action.payload.project
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default function ImagesReducer (state = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
            return // do your update with action.payload.images
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

You can see the same pattern in the ngrx examples application.  In both reducers ADD_TO_CART is being listened to:

https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-examples/blob/master/shopping-cart/src/app/reducers/products.ts

https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-examples/blob/master/shopping-cart/src/app/reducers/cart.ts

Comment: This is close to what I need. However, because the action isn't called this.otherService.loadImagesSuccess(images) is never fired, the payload doesn't change the state. Is there a way to map the results of loadImages() to loadImagesSuccess(), and then fire uploadImagesSuccess(project).

Comment: Instead of having the load image success action can you just have uploadImagesSuccess do what load image success action would have done?  Therefore uploadImagesSuccess would be doing 2 things.

Comment: Not sure if that will work. The loadImagesSuccess returns a normalized list of all my images. I need that data sent to my ImagesReducer. Something like: .map(images => this.imageService.loadImagesSuccess(images)). The uploadImagesSuccess returns my project data, in which project images are stored as a list of ids. I send that data to my ProjectReducer via: .map(project => this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess(project)). Basically, loadImages needs to change the ImageState, and uploadImagesSuccess needs to change the ProjectState.

Comment: I don't think I can have the list of images from the loadImages() payload update the ImageState from uploadImagesSuccess. Both are intended to change different parts of my store. I could be thinking of this all incorrectly, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to describe how to do this.  I hope this helps!

Comment: For me, the second mergeMap needed to be  .mergeMap(project => {. Otherwise it was returning the action.payload. However this worked even better than I could have hoped for. Learned a few new things in the process, never came across those other examples either. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use concat:

```
@Effect() uploadImages$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ProjectActions.UPLOAD_IMAGES)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .flatMap(project => this.service.uploadImages(project))
    .switchMap((project) => Observable.concat(
      this.imageActions.loadImages(),
      this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess(project),
    ));
```

Or from:

```
 @Effect() uploadImages$ = this.actions$
      .ofType(ProjectActions.UPLOAD_IMAGES)
      .map(action => action.payload)
      .flatMap(project => this.service.uploadImages(project))
        .switchMap((project) => Observable.from([
          this.imageActions.loadImages(),
          this.projectActions.uploadImagesSuccess(project)]
        ));
```

Comment: that's not doing anything different for me. I was initially getting errors, but it was just that I had forgot the brackets. Otherwise, this is still giving me the same results.